# delete rows older than one day beginning with the fifth row

Tags: mysql

How can I delete all rows that are older than one day but starting with the fifth row (if it exists!)?

Layout of the MYSQL db:

```
user |post|timestamp
Harry foo  1445275458
```

(Timestamp is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: How do you determine "The fifth row"? Is it the fifth row when sorted by timestamp desc?

Comment: @JNevill fifth row is the fifth row sorted by timestamp descending

Comment: So what you _actually_ want to do is delete everything more that 24 hours old, but make sure to keep the five newest entries regardless of age. (and is it 24 hours, or is it `day < today` even if that's just 2 hours?) — stated another way ... "I always want to keep the five newest entries, and all entries from today. Delete everything else".  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, did not word it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this sample data shamelessly stolen by Drew and extended:

```
select t1.*, from_unixtime(tstamp) from t1;

| id | fname | lname |     tstamp |     from_unixtime(tstamp) |
|----|-------|-------|------------|---------------------------|
|  1 | Harry |   foo | 1445275458 | October, 19 2015 17:24:18 |
|  2 | Harry |   foo | 1445275457 | October, 19 2015 17:24:17 |
|  3 | Harry |   foo | 1445275456 | October, 19 2015 17:24:16 |
|  4 | Harry |   foo | 1445275455 | October, 19 2015 17:24:15 |
|  5 | Harry |   foo | 1445275454 | October, 19 2015 17:24:14 |
|  6 | Harry |   foo | 1445275453 | October, 19 2015 17:24:13 |
|  7 | Harry |   foo | 1445275452 | October, 19 2015 17:24:12 |
|  8 | Harry |   foo | 1345275458 |  August, 18 2012 07:37:38 |
|  9 | Harry |   foo | 1435275458 |    June, 25 2015 23:37:38 |
```

With this query

```
DELETE t1.* 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM t1 ORDER BY tstamp DESC LIMIT 5) q ON t1.id = q.id
WHERE q.id IS NULL
AND t1.tstamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

you get the following result:

```
select t1.*, from_unixtime(tstamp) from t1;

| id | fname | lname |     tstamp |     from_unixtime(tstamp) |
|----|-------|-------|------------|---------------------------|
|  1 | Harry |   foo | 1445275458 | October, 19 2015 17:24:18 |
|  2 | Harry |   foo | 1445275457 | October, 19 2015 17:24:17 |
|  3 | Harry |   foo | 1445275456 | October, 19 2015 17:24:16 |
|  4 | Harry |   foo | 1445275455 | October, 19 2015 17:24:15 |
|  5 | Harry |   foo | 1445275454 | October, 19 2015 17:24:14 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/621a1/1/0)